# What is wrong with this date string? causing: "Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException"

Tags: datetime, f#

I call my script like this:

```
>Driver.exe 26268 "01-01-2011" "02-01-2011"

arg 0 : c:\Services\JasperBatchService\Release\JasperBatchDriver.exe
arg 1 : 26268

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,  DateTimeStyles style)
   at Program.main(String[] args) in C:\sswork\dev\fSharpServices\ops-Projects\JasperBatchDriver\Program.fs:line 65
```

and this is the relavent code:

```
let mutable argNum = 0
let cmdArgs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()    

for arg in cmdArgs do
    match argNum with
    | 1 -> pmID      <- System.Int32.Parse arg 
    | 2 -> startDate <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "D", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | 3 -> endDate   <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "D", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | _ -> ()
    printfn "arg %d : %s" argNum arg
    argNum <- argNum + 1
```

i've also tried this:

```
for arg in cmdArgs do
    match argNum with
    | 1 -> pmID      <- System.Int32.Parse arg 
    | 2 -> startDate <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | 3 -> endDate   <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | _ -> ()
    printfn "arg %d : %s" argNum arg
    argNum <- argNum + 1
```

and this:

```
for arg in cmdArgs do
    match argNum with
    | 1 -> pmID      <- System.Int32.Parse arg 
    | 2 -> startDate <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | 3 -> endDate   <- DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
    | _ -> ()
    printfn "arg %d : %s" argNum arg
    argNum <- argNum + 1
```

the closest it seems I came is by using this:

```
(startDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

this however added double-quotes to the output....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your calls to DateTime.ParseExact are expecting the "D" (Long Date pattern) format, which is different than what you're providing.  If you plan on accepting arguments in the MM-DD-YYYY format, you'll need to use a custom format instead.

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(arg, "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: The code BHSPitMonkey posted works just fine with both of the date strings in your example. If it's still not working, then the exact value of `arg` is not `01-01-2011` or `02-01-2011`. You're going to need to provide more details than "still choking" if you want any further suggestions.

Comment: I suspect that the value of `arg` is not `01-01-2011` but `"01-01-2011"`. If the quotes are part of the string, then it won't match the pattern. If so, you need to either add escaped quotes to the pattern, or remove them from your command line. Either way, printing out the value that ParseExact is choking on ought to help.

Answer (score 1):

this works (from fsi):

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact ("01-01-2011", "MM-dd-yyyy",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo "en-US");;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM {Date = 1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM;
                                             Day = 1;
                                             DayOfWeek = Saturday;
                                             DayOfYear = 1;
                                             Hour = 0;
                                             Kind = Unspecified;
                                             Millisecond = 0;
                                             Minute = 0;
                                             Month = 1;
                                             Second = 0;
                                             Ticks = 634294368000000000L;
                                             TimeOfDay = 00:00:00;
                                             Year = 2011;}
```

how are you iterating through the args array? isn't the mutable argNum always 0?

Comment: no, this is the last line of the for loop: argNum <- argNum + 1

Answer (score 0):

arg 2 should be in this format 01-01-2011

Comment: Seems format string "D" cannot be used. When i try with "MM-dd-yyyy", it works.